# Datatable for pagination and searching for live data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, mean-stack

I tried using datatables for live data but my problem is, every time my data updates, I can't use searching and every time I use pagination, it goes back to first page. Can somebody knows what datatable plugin is compatible with angular?

**Here is my code for realtime update of data:**

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope','$interval', function($scope,$interval) {
  $interval(function () {
    $scope.register = {
      regData: {
        branch: {},
      },
      names: [
        {name:"narquois"},{name:"vorpal"},{name:"keen"},
        {name:"argol"},{name:"long"},{name:"propolis"},
        {name:"bees"},{name:"film"},{name:"dipsetic"},
        {name:"thirsty"},{name:"opacity"},{name:"simplex"},
        {name:"jurel"},{name:"coastal "},{name:"fish"},
        {name:"kraken"},{name:"woman"},{name:"limp"},
      ],
    };
    }, 1000);
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
<table id="example" width="100%">
    <thead>
       <tr align="center">
         <th>Name</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="person in register.names">
         <td align="center">{{ person.name }}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable state saving and override state save/load handlers to use only the table's DOM id:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  stateSave: true,
  stateSaveCallback: function(settings,data) {
      localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance, JSON.stringify(data) )
    },
  stateLoadCallback: function(settings) {
    return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance ) )
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your DataTable with the option [stateSave](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave). It enables you to keep the pagination, filter values, and sorting of your table on page refresh. It uses HTML5's APIs `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    stateSave: true
});
```